# Java Drag and Drop Show Item Being Dragged

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I've implemented drag and drop in my JTree, but I'm wondering is there a way to show the item(s) being dragged while dragging (such as when dragging in Windows Explorer or dragging files in Eclipse for example)?

Comment: I only see the cursor when I'm dragging. It will show the no-drop symbol if it cannot be dropped, but I'd like to show the actual object I'm dragging.

Comment: no idea, you have to create Dragable JToolTip, JWindow, JPanel and there copy content of node during drag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to add an additional layer (JPanel) over your app to render the images as they drag.  Romain Guy wrote a slick and easy example of this a few years ago:

http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/drag_with_style_in_swing